# Google Maps Android Api V2 Driving Route Isn't Working

Tags: android, google-maps, drawing, routes

i don't have any idea why my code is not working... I made a ListArray that which keep my CurrentPosition continuosly and draw it with a polyline. here is my code.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.pondys.limon.touregsys;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.SyncStateContract.Constants;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener  {
    GoogleMap googleMap;
    double latitude,longitude,firstLatitude,firstLongitude;
    private ArrayList<LatLng> arrayPoints = null;
    PolylineOptions polylineOptions;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_main.xml
        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
        googleMap = fm.getMap();
        // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
     // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        // Getting the name of the best provider
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        // Getting Current Location
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

     // Getting latitude of the current location
             firstLatitude = location.getLatitude();

            // Getting longitude of the current location
             firstLongitude = location.getLongitude();      

        CameraUpdate center=
                CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(latitude,longitude));
            CameraUpdate zoom=CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15);
            googleMap.moveCamera(center);
            googleMap.animateCamera(zoom);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        // Getting latitude of the current location
        latitude = location.getLatitude();

        // Getting longitude of the current location
        longitude = location.getLongitude();

        // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng (latitude,longitude);
        ArrayList<LatLng> list = new ArrayList<LatLng> ();
        list.add(latLng);

        // Showing the current location in Google Map
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        // Zoom in the Google Map
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

        PolylineOptions o = new PolylineOptions ().width(3).color(0xFFEE8888);
        for(int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++){
            o.add(new LatLng(latitude,longitude));
        }

        googleMap.addPolyline(o);

        }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

there is no any route showing when i execute it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do it like this :

```
Polyline pathOptions = googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().add(new LatLng(source_latitude, source_longitude), new LatLng(destination_latitude, destination_longitude)));

// Set the polyline's color to blue
pathOptions.setColor(Color.BLUE);

// Set the polyline's width
pathOptions.setWidth(2);
```